# Perfect preimages of compact spaces are compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Below is a question concerning compact spaces from James Munkres' *Topology*. Following that is my attempt at a solution, which I am not sure is correct and would appreciate if somebody could point out what (if anything) is wrong with it.

**Question:** Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a closed continuous surjective map such that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact, for each $y\in Y$. Show that if $Y$ is compact, then $X$ is compact.

**Attempted Solution:** Let $\mathcal{A}=\{{U_{\alpha}}\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be an indexed family of open sets that covers $X$. Let $\mathcal{A}_{y}$ denote the subcollection of $\mathcal{A}$ covering $p^{-1}(\{y\})$. Since $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for each $y\in Y$, there exists a finite subcollection $\mathcal{B}_{y}$ of $\mathcal{A}_{y}$ covering $p^{-1}(\{y\})$. Let $B_{y}$ denote the union of all open sets in $\mathcal{B}_{y}$. Then $X-B_{y}$ is closed in $X$ and since $p$ is closed, $p(X-B_{y})$ is closed in $Y$.

Cover $Y$ by the collection $\{Y-p(X-B_{y})$|$y\in Y\}$ of open sets. We can do so, because for any $y\in Y$, the open set $B_{y}$ contains the inverse image $p^{-1}(\{y\})$, so that $p(X-B_{y})$ doesn't contain $y$ and $y\in Y-p(X-B_{y})$. Then, since $Y$ is compact, there exists a finite subcollection

$\{Y-p(X-B_{y_1}), Y-p(X-B_{y_{2}}),....Y-p(X-B_{{y}_{n}})\}$................(1)

covering $Y$. Furthermore, each of the $Y-p(X-B_{y_{i}})$ contains only those points $y$ whose inverse images $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is contained in $B_{y_{i}}$. Therefore $p^{-1}(Y-p(X-B_{y_{i}}))\subseteq B_{y_{i}}$. So, if the subcollection given by (1) is an open covering of $Y$, then

$\{p^{-1}(Y-p(X-B_{y_{1}})), p^{-1}(Y-p(X-B_{y_{2}})),.....p^{-1}(Y-p(X-B_{y_{n}})) \}$

is an open covering of $X$ and by virtue of containing the set $p^{-1}(Y-p(X-B_{y_{i}}))$ for every $i$, the collection $\{B_{y_{1}}, B_{y_{2}},...B_{y_{n}}\}$ also covers $X$. Since each of the $B_{y_{i}}$ is itself covered by the finite subcollection  $\mathcal{B}_{y_{i}}$, the finite subcollection $\cup _{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{B}_{y_{i}}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ also covers $X$. Hence $X$ is compact.

Comment: It's right. In fact, this result belongs to the study of _proper mappings_. These are closed mappings with compact fibers (a possible definition) and have the property that inverse images of compact sets are compact. For the converse, some assumption is needed on the target (e.g. locally compact and Hausdorff)